# WPF Application Hang OnUserPreferenceChanging()

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I Got a WPF Application that hang on random.. (look like thread synchronisation, no CPU Usage / dead lock ??)

When I look at the dump file, the main UI thread is stop on DispatcherSynchronizationContext when OnUserPreferenceChanging() called

see link : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943139/windows-forms-application-freezes-when-system-settings-are-changed-or

So I use SPY++ to check, I found that I got two thread that have Windows (not mine)

1. is GDI+ (always present when application running and hang)
2. is SystemResourceNotifyWindow  (always present when is hanged)

The seconds one is causing the problem (I think)

The OnUserPreferenceChanging() is called severa time without hanging (log used)

All controls/windows are created with Dispatcher (Invoke or BeginInvode)

Any way to find when this windows is created ?
Any idea how to fix ?

Comment: Are you creating controls on non-UI threads?

Comment: I can neither confirm nor deny a bug in your code that I have not seen. [mcve]

Comment: Seeing that SystemResourceNotifyWindow being owned by another thread is the bug, it must be owned by the main thread.  Tends to be caused by creating a WPF window on a worker thread.  Ensure Just My Code is turned off and the Symbol Server enabled.  Debug > New Breakpoint > Function Breakpoint and type System.Windows.SystemResources.EnsureResourceChangeListener.  When it hits look at the Call Stack window to find the evil code.